# How can I change the bar width in seaborn plots?

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, catplot, countplot

Each bar has large width

[image]

How can I reduce the width of bars, as shown by the drawn red rectangles?

I have the following code in Google Colab.

```
model_names = ['RFC', 'KNN', 'D-tree',  'SVM RBF']
accuracies = [0.999, 0.970, 0.997, 0.985]

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2))

ax = sns.barplot(x=model_names, y=accuracies)
plt.xlabel('Model')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Model Accuracies Comparison ')

for i, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
    ax.annotate('{:.3f}'.format(accuracy), xy=(i, accuracy),      xycoords='data', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

- [`seaborn v0.12.0`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.12.0.html#other-updates) introduced the `width` parameter to [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

  - Google Colab appears to currently be using `seaborn 0.12.2` and `matplotlib 3.7.1`.
  - Also applies to:

    - `sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', ..., width=0.5)`
    - `sns.catplot(data=df, kind='count', ..., width=0.5)`
    - `sns.countplot(data=df, ..., width=0.5)`
- [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) describes using `.bar_label`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample dataframe
df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

# without width
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', errorbar=None)
ax.set(title='Without width=')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])

# with width
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', errorbar=None, width=0.5)
ax.set(title='With width=0.5')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

[image]

[image]

---

```py
model_names = ['RFC', 'KNN', 'D-tree',  'SVM RBF']
accuracies = [0.999, 0.970, 0.997, 0.985]

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))

# specify width
ax = sns.barplot(x=model_names, y=accuracies, width=0.5)
ax.set(xlabel='Model', ylabel='Accuracy', title='Comparison')

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
ax.margins(y=0.15)

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]